# Why does appending to one list also append to all other lists in my list of lists?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I do the following:

```
>>> l = [[]]*2
>>> l
[[], []]
>>> l[0].append(1)
>>> l
[[1], [1]]
```

Why does 1 get appended to both lists?

Comment: This issue is discussed in http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#id38 resp. http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`[[]]*2` is a list of two references to **the same list**. You are appending to it and then seeing it twice.

Answer (score 14):

Because there is really only one list. Consider this:

```
>>> l = [[]]
>>> l2 = l*2
>>> l2[0] is l[0]
True
>>> l2[1] is l[0]
True
```

`*2` performed on a list does not copy the list but return a list of length `2` filled with the same reference.

What you probably wanted was this:

```
>>> l = [[] for _ in xrange(2)]
```

As @Asterisk mentions in a comment, the same behaviour is exposed by all common collections. As a rule of thumb it is therefore best to **only use multiplication on immutable types with value-semantics**.

Comment: it seems *2 performed on dictionary does not copy as well...

Answer (score 5):

**Showcasing the difference with memory layout:**

```
listOfLists = [[]] * 3
listOfListsRange = [[] for i in range(0, 3)]
```

[run in pythontutor](https://pythontutor.com/python-debugger.html#code=listOfLists%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5D%5D%20*%203%0AlistOfListsRange%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5D%20for%20i%20in%20range%280,%203%29%5D&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

[image: memory layout shown in python tutor]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i initialize a list of lists. Rows vary slowest.

```
nrows = 3; ncols = 5

l_of_ls = [[0]*ncols for i in range(nrows )]

for rix, r in enumerate(l_of_ls):
    for cix, c in enumerate(r):
        print rix, cix, 'val = ',c
```

**RESULT**

```
0 0 val =  0
0 1 val =  0
0 2 val =  0
0 3 val =  0
0 4 val =  0
1 0 val =  0
1 1 val =  0
1 2 val =  0
1 3 val =  0
1 4 val =  0
2 0 val =  0
2 1 val =  0
2 2 val =  0
2 3 val =  0
2 4 val =  0
```

**Also Worth Noting for Indexing Purposes**

```
for rix in range(nrows):
    for cix in range(ncols):
        print l_of_ls[rix][cix],
    print
```

**RESULT**

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```