# Python nested lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python list append behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255383/python-list-append-behavior)

Why does this code:

```
x = [[]]*3
x[0].append('a')
x[1].append('b')
x[2].append('c')
x[0]=['d']

print x
```

print [['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]?

Comment: This question is literally asked about once a day... The problem seems to be that you can't search for the solution unless you already know what's going on.

Comment: to prohibit such behaviour, it's better to create list of lists using this following syntax.>>>
x=[[] for _ in range(3)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is best explained step by step:

```
>>> x = [[]]*3
>>> x
[[], [], []]
>>> x[0].append('a')
>>> x
[['a'], ['a'], ['a']]
>>> x[1].append('b')
>>> x
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
>>> x[2].append('c')
>>> x
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
>>> x[0]=['d']
>>> x
[['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

The first statement creates a list with three references to the same element in it. So when you modify the first element, you're also modifying the second and third element. Hence, the append statements add a number to each of the elements of the list.

Comment: I know it's tempting but there are already 50 good answers to this question. Just link a duplciate in a comment and / or flag it as a duplicate until you have enough rep to vote to close.

Comment: Operator * acting on the lists makes shallow copies — that is.