# How to search for all occurences of a key in a deeply nested json file?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I want to be able to find all occurrences of a particular json object in a json file using one of the keys that it has. For instance if I have the following json block :

```
{
                  "FNMIP": 1,
                  "FNMIT": 0,
                  "FNMP": {
                    "DP": {
                      "DT": 0,
                      "UF": true,
                      "DF": "yyyyMMdd"
                    },
                    "FP": {
                      "FE": null
                    }
                  },
                  "IE": true,
                  "$": "PMF"
                }
```

I want to search for all the json block that contain this key and then apply some kind a logic to replace it with another json object. I am not able to figure out as to how to do that stuff in Python as I am new to Python.

Comment: So, you want to do a DFS search, and when you find a match, append that object to an array?  You will just need to recursively walk it

Comment: I get the idea of doing depth first search, what I want to do is do a DFS and when I find that object replace it with a new object and continue my search to look for more objects of that type.

Comment: could you provide an example data and modification? You might want to look into [the documentation on `dict` object type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to recursively walk nested `dict`s and for any value that matches a particular value replace it with something else. so do this:

```
def recursive_replace(data,match,repl):
    for k,v in data.items():
        if v == match:
            data[k] = repl #replace the matched value
        elif isinstance(v,dict):
            recursive_replace(v,match,repl)
```

then you can just convert the data back into json.

to instead test if `"$"` key is present in the data you can use the `in` operator:

```
def recursive_replace(data,repl):
    for k,v in data.items():
        if not isinstance(v,dict):
            continue
        elif "$" in v:
            data[k] = repl
        else:
            recursive_replace(v,repl)
```

Comment: so, the thing is when I see that for json object like the one above if "$":"PMF" then replace it with a new object altogether.

Comment: _replace it with a new object_ like what? Is it a static value or determined based on where the data is located in the grand scheme of things?  do you want data like `{"tadhg":{"$":"A"},"Ankit":{"$":"B"}}` to replace the "$" key with the key from one level up in the structure?  So that the new data is like `{"tadhg":{"tadhg":"A"},"Ankit":{"Ankit":"B"}}`

Comment: No, so if I find something with "$":"A" then I want to replace the parent object that can be dictionary in which "$" is a key with a new dictionary so if the structure was like {"X": "S", "V": { "$" : PFM}} then replace it with {"P": "A"} for example.

Comment: I added to the answer but I'm still unclear if this is what you want.  How is the replacement value being defined?  If you simply replace all the values with a single dictionary they will all end up being references to the same object and you will get problems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255383/python-list-append-behavior

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen this was a nice solution for a similar problem I had. Thank you!