# Python: Changing a single object within an array of objects changes all, even in a different array

Tags: python, arrays, object

I've got a one type of object, `data_entry`, that has a 2-dimensional array of other objects, `time_entry`.

Initialization of  time_entries the array within `data_entry` looks like this:

```
[([time_entry()] * 12) for i in range(5)]
```

and initialization of the `data_entry` looks like this:

```
thing = data_entry()
```

Now, I have a list of "things", each which contains it's own 2d array of `time_entry`s.

Each `time_entry` has a list as one of it's attributes, initialized like so:

```
attributes = []
```

I modify attributes by extending it using `.extend()`.

However, the problem I run into when I do this is EVERY single `time_entry` object in EVERY single `data_entry` object gets extended.

I know problems like this can arise from improper initialization of objects, so I'm wondering if perhaps my object creations are poor or there  is another python quirk I am unaware of.

Comment: can you post a minimal working example?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: I am afraid the answer to that question solves a different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are performing the initialization on the class, it will affect all instances of the class. If that’s the case, this is not a result of it being in a list, but of it being on the class. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class BedrockDenizen():
    attributes = []


wilma = BedrockDenizen()
fred = BedrockDenizen()

wilma.attributes.extend(['thin', 'smart'])
fred.attributes.extend(['fat', 'stupid'])

print 'Wilma:', wilma.attributes
print 'Fred:', fred.attributes
```

You will see that both Fred and Wilma are thin, smart, fat, and stupid.

> Wilma: ['thin', 'smart', 'fat', 'stupid']
>
> Fred: ['thin', 'smart', 'fat', 'stupid']

One way to fix this is to put the attribute creation into the **init** method, so that the attribute is per-instance:

```
class BedrockDenizen():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attributes = []
```

With that change, only Wilma is thin and smart, and only Fred is fat and stupid.

> Wilma: ['thin', 'smart']
>
> Fred: ['fat', 'stupid']

You may also need to show us more code. @Bakuriu notes that the problem may be that you are only creating one instance, and he may be right. For example, if this is closer to your code:

```
class BedrockDenizen():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attributes = []

neighborhood = [([BedrockDenizen()] * 2) for i in range(2)]

flintstones, rubbles = neighborhood
fred, wilma = flintstones

wilma.attributes.extend(['thin', 'smart'])
fred.attributes.extend(['fat', 'stupid'])

print 'Wilma:', wilma.attributes
print 'Fred:', fred.attributes
```

Then Fred and Wilma will continue to have the same attributes, because they aren’t really separate people. You may wish to use code more like this:

```
class BedrockDenizen():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attributes = []

neighborhood = [[BedrockDenizen() for n in range(2)] for i in range(2)]

flintstones, rubbles = neighborhood
fred, wilma = flintstones

wilma.attributes.extend(['thin', 'smart'])
fred.attributes.extend(['fat', 'stupid'])

print 'Wilma:', wilma.attributes
print 'Fred:', fred.attributes
```

That depends on what your needs are, though, as it seems like an odd way of doing things without more info.

Comment: This is a **different, unrelated** issue. I don't see any `[object] * number` in this code which is what is causing OP's problems.

Comment: @JerryStratton: No, `[object] * n` creates a list of `n` entries, all of which are the same object. It doesn't make new objects.

Comment: Yea I think this might be right. Give it a try OP

Comment: Yes, I was misreading your comment, @Bakuriu. But I still think that the OP’s problem occurs with the “extend”. I could be wrong, though. I’ve added a new option to the answer.

Comment: This seems to have been the problem - attributes was was initialized within the class rather than in the constructor.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your attributes all point to the same list object inside. Then you call extend on the **same object** every time and modify it.

This is a common issue and discussed at
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list and [Python list append behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255383/python-list-append-behavior)